# I need to move one side of a rod along a path but anchor the other side still

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, parent, path

I have a long rod object, one side of the rod needs to follow a circular path, while the other side is anchored to another object. I want it to be able to move slightly so that the path following end can go all the way around, but I want it to have to stay touching the anchoring object. I don't know if I can do this efficiently or if I'm even explaining it well. I attached an image to maybe help demonstrate what I mean a little better. It's such a specific question that I've had a really hard time trying to research it, so I simply tried to look into curves, paths, parenting and that kind of thing and couldn't find anything that helped me.[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blend file below...

[image]

The circular path -

Add the circle path and scale it to suit.  APPLY the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
Bevel it when it has to be rendered.

In it's curve properties at right, set it's "Frames" to (e.g.) 20.

Set the timeline to frame 1 and in the curve's "Evaluation" slot, set that to zero and keyframe. (<kbd>I</kbd>)

Move the timeline to frame 20 and again in the path's evaluation slot, set that to 20 and keyframe.

Goto the Dopesheet and with the circle-path still selected, select both keyframes and press <kbd>T</kbd> --> "Linear".

-==========-

The path object - (empty)

Using the path's origin point, make sure the cursor is still set to that with SH-S.

Add an Empty.  Scale it to suit and 'APPLY' the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> .

Give it a "Follow Path" constraint.  Name the Curve-path as the 'Target'.

Play the animation and check the empty's travel is constant and is traveling around the curve properly.

Add a cube somewhere distant.

In Edit mode, select the vertical edge (corner edge) that's nearest the path.  Subdivide that with 'W'.
This will be the 'anchor point' for the rod.

-================-

The rod -

Add a cylinder and scale it to suit. APPLY the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.  Locate and rotate it roughly so it's pointing to both the path and cube.

Set it's origin point to the circle-path end so it will pivot from that end.

Give the rod a "Track To" constraint and name the cube as the target.

Enter the start & end frames for the timeline as 1 to 20.

Play the animation and the rod should 'crank' around the circle, always pointing to the cube.

-================-

When the rod must always be connected to the cube...

Add a hook at the rod's cube end and parent that to the cube.  (child = hook)  Drag the hook so they're connected.

[image]